# The server closed the connection without sending any data

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, download

I just started to program web servers and I downloaded one of the samples from here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17071/Sample-HTTP-Server-Skeleton-in-C

When I try to open(download) any other file other than htm extension, I get an error from my browser saying that

> "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

I **cannot debug** the problem as program itself is **not crushing**. I am assuming that this has to do with file request types but I have no clue where to start at.

So what is it missing here and what should I do?

Comment: It can be a good exercise to learn the HTTP protocol but you already have a built-in [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Comment: Try wireshark or something to see what data you are sending/receving